# What are the font attributes of the text in prefersLargeTitles property?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit, preferslargetitles

I'm trying to re-create the look of the prefersLargeTitles property. To that end, I was wondering if anyone can tell me the font and font size used for this property?

The reason why I'm trying to re-create this on my own is that when I hide the navigation bar in my view controller, the prefersLargeTitles property becomes automatically disabled and hidden. So the goal is to re-create this property as a custom UILabel instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL:DR

| Font | Color |
| --- | --- |
| SFUI-Bold 34.00pt | labelColor |

You can check using the [Debug View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html).

[image: Debug View Hierarchy]

#### Here's all the properties:

Object

| Class name | Address |
| --- | --- |
| UILabel | 0x13680d3b0 |

Label

| Text | Text | Lines | Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Title | White:0 Alpha:1 (**labelColor**) | 1 | Enabled On |
| Plain Text | **.SFUI-Bold 34.00pt** |  | Highlighted off |
|  | Aligned Natural |  |  |

| Baseline | Line Break | Min Font Scale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Align Baselines | Truncate Tail | 0 |

| Highlighted | Shadow | Shadow Offset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nil color | nil color | w `0` h `-1` |

View

| Layer | Layer Class | Content Mode | Tag | Interaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <_UILabelLayer: 0x600003cae350> | _UILabelLayer | Left | 0 | User Interaction Enabled Off, Multiple Touch Off |

| Alpha | Background | Tint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | White:0 Alpha:0 (clearColor) | R:0 G:0.48 B:1 A:1 (systemBlueColor) |

| Drawing |
| --- |
| Opaque On |
| Hidden Off |
| Clears Graphics Context On |
| Clip To Bounds Off |
| Autoresize Subviews On |

Accessibility (Is Accessibility Element, Not Focused)

| Value | Traits | Elements | Description | Hint | Identifier | Actions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | Header | null | Title | null | null | null |

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the values from the [Typography section of the Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) as they can vary from 31pt to 60pt depending on the user's chosen font size with Dynamic Type. There are separate tables for the base sizes:

[image]

and the accessibility sizes:

[image]

If you want to implement as a custom label for whatever reason, you can just let dynamic type do that for you rather than specifying exact point sizes as well:

```
mylabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
```